# Waiting in Background process in C program in Unix

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix

Im trying to emulate shell through C program. In my program whenever I run any normal (foreground) commands it works fine. Also I have handled background process with commands ending with '&'. Now to handle this I have avoided the parent waiting for a child process.

The problem is whenever for the first time in my shell I run any background command(i.e ending in '&') then it works fine. But then after that each command(normal) doesnot terminate. I guess it waits for the previously opened process. How to rectify. Please you can ask questions so that i can make myself more clear to you. This is the snippet which is doing the above mentioned task.

```
child_id=fork();
if(child_id==0){
        //logic fo creating command
        int ret=execvp(subcomm[0],subcomm);
}
//Child will never come here if execvp executed successfully
if(proc_sate!='&'){
        for(i=0;i<count_pipe+1;i++){            
            waitpid(0,&flag,0);
            }
        //something to add to make it not wait for other process in my scenario for second time 
}
```

Here proc_state just determines whether it is background or foreground.It is just a character. count_pipe is just a variable holding number of pipes (e.g ls -l|wc|wc this contains 2 pipes). Dont worry this all is working fine.

Comment: Please show how you are starting the processes in "your" shell.

Comment: Edited the question.Please check

Comment: You should throw an exception or something if execvp fails. Don't let it fall-thru to the next line. You want your child to exit immediately, not `waitpid`.

Comment: Don't throw exceptions. Just print an error message and exit(). And use some whitespace, for heaven's sake.

Comment: Sorry i have not included that but i have handled it. Dont Worry execvp is working fine. Just the above mentioned issue still remains

Comment: No loop is just for waiting for multiple forked childs..As i said earlier that all is working fine. Now with setsid even the above problem is rectified. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitpid(0, &flag, 0)` waits for any child process whose process group ID is equal to that of your shell. So if you have not called `setsid()` after the `fork()` of the disconnected child process, the code above will wait for that too.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
    setsid(); /* Child creates new process group */
    ... /* redirections, etc */
    execvp(...);
}
```

Comment: setsid I guess creating a process in new session. Which is not returning signal to parent. So now my program is waiting even for foreground process if I try this

Comment: I meant this only for programs started with '&'.

Comment: Can I have my upvote please? My new hobby is collecting Stackoverflow points, you know... :-)

Comment: signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN) even this will work I guess because it removes the children that terminates later. And avoid turning then into zombie.

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow. So it is showing not enough points to upvote. Sorry. Thanks for reply anyways :)

Comment: That's outrageous :-)